# How to pass hidden field value from asp page to another in anchor tag

Tags: asp.net, html

I have tried passing the hidden field value using href. Below is the code snippet for the same and it is not working. I do not want to use java script function as I want this to work in a particular scenario when java script is disabled by the user. Value of the variable is set in code behind

```
<form name ="hiddenform" method="get" action="a1.asp">
<input type="hidden" id="hasflash" value=" " />

<div class="header" id="check" style="color: red;">
please <a href="a1.asp?hasflash"+<%=hasflash.Value%>>upgrade your add-on software</a>
</div>
```

I have also tried the below code:

```
<div class="header" id="check" style="color: red;">
please <a href=("a1.asp?hasflash={0}",hasflash.Value)>upgrade your add-on software</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add `runat="server"` to your hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hasflash" Value="SomeValues" />
```

Then you can achieve that in 2 or more ways

```
please <a href="a1.asp?hasflash=<%=hasflash.Value %>">upgrade your add-on software</a>
```

or

```
please <a href='<%= String.Format("a1.asp?hasflash={0}",hasflash.Value) %>'>upgrade your add-on software</a>
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when I use the first answer: my script is exactly like yours: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' Object required: ''

Comment: i'm sorry. but the script was tested and it worked. i don't know what you did wrong. did  you add `runat="server"`?

Comment: My bad. The value from the code behind wasn't setting properly. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<div class="header" id="check" style="color: red;">
     please <a href="a1.asp?hasflash=<%=hasflash.Value%>">upgrade your add-on software</a>
</div>
```